# Windows Client Auto Logon After Logoff

Tags: windows, login

I've seen this done before and I'm trying to figure out how it was accomplished now that I've had the opportunity thrown in my lap. Or more like it was placed there by me since I saw an opportunity to do it.

Automatic user logon with Windows isn't a big deal and I've got that part well ironed out and included in a GPO (I know, don't shoot me). However what I can't seem to be able to figure out is that if the person at the computer issues a logout action and logs out, how to make the computer automatically re-log as the same account that just logged off.

Now before anyone goes "STFU and use GPO to remove the logoff button from the Start Menu" or "Remove it from the three-finger-salute menu with a GPO," I already know that's possible. I just want to replicate this behavior.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd really like to hear them! Let's chat!

Thanks!

Comment: But my system is so awesome that they have no choice! :P

Comment: @Ryan, if it's not possible this should be an answer, opposed to a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No... you can't make someone log on against their will.

Edit: OK... you *might* be able to do something funny with [a custom GINA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375457(VS.85).aspx) (if using Windows XP) or [a Credential Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx) (if using Vista or above.)  Credential Providers have to be in native code, so no .NET, etc.. The effort required would be significant.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, it's not about forcing a physical person to log back in.

Comment: A company I used to work for had a series of computers that existed in a specific OU that, when a user logged out of the designated account, they would automatically be logged back into the same account. That's what I'm trying to accomplish here. Functionality similar to a kiosk.

Comment: The proper thing to do in a kiosk scenario is to prevent the user from logging off in the first place.

Comment: Yeah I understand that and that's great and what's going on but I'm trying to figure out how they accomplished something like what I saw in that environment.

Comment: Edited. I'm trying to throw you a bone here. :)

Comment: Thanks for that! Just trying to sate some curiosity here. I appreciate it!

Comment: I wasn't planning on implementing this on my network. More or less it was just something that had crossed my mind while I was working on policies.

Comment: @gregfmartin When post a question just out of curiosity, please state that in the question as a courtesy.  Some of us will spend a significant amount of time looking for a solution, and that would help us prioritize where we spend our time.